# SSL certificates for a mixture of subdomains and top level domains

Tags: tls, certificates

In order to provide https-enabled access to several (e.g. around 5) subdomains and several top level domains on different IPs.

Which of the following approaches is technically feasible?

1. a one-use SSL certificate for each subdomain and domain
2. a multi-domain certificate
3. a mixture of wildcard and single domain
4. a mixture of wildcard and multi-domain certificates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "feasible/straightforward" in terms of security. There is certainly a big different in costs, but cost considerations are off-topic here. Logistical considerations as a server admin are better asked on Serverfault or Webmasters.

Comment: Is it technically possible to implement with all of the options described, or do only some of them apply, do you know?

Answer (score 2):

All of these approaches are technically feasible, i.e. they can be generated and browsers will accept these. But while you can create such certificates using your own CA it does not mean that every CA will support issuing all of these variations.

In case of using a single certificate for each different name you have to make sure that either each of these names points to a different IP address or that your server and client both support [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). While this is true for all modern browsers and web servers you might get problems with older browser or applications or with protocols outside HTTP.

Comment: One policy constraint: if you want EV -- and whether you should want EV is a different question -- CABforum prohibits wildcards in EV certs.